# Determine the time complexity of repeated logarithm until not greater than 1

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, optimization

```
    t <- n
    while t>1 do
        t <- log_2(t)
```

I tried to do it this way:
$f^\text{(1)}(t)=\log_2(t) \\ f^\text{(2)}(t)=\log_2\log_2(t) = \log_2^{(2)}(t) \\f^\text{(3)}(t) = \log_2^{(3)}(t) \\ f^\text{(j-1)}(t) = \log_2^{(j-1)}(t) \\ f^\text{(j)}(t) = \log_2\log_2^{(j-1)}(t) = log_2^{(j)}(t) $

I consider $f^{(j)}(t)$ the function $f(t)$ iterated $j$ times.

Now I need to find out $\min\{j: f^{(j)}(t) > 1\} = \min\{j:\log_2^{(j)}(t) > 1\}$.

But I can't find a way to determine $j$, so I think there's a different way to calculate the complexity of this algorithm, some idea?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

Answer (score 1):

The complexity in terms of the number of logarithm evaluations is expressed by the *iterated logarithm* function. There is no better expression.

Note the following values:

$$[0,1]\to0\\(1,2]\to1\\(2,4]\to2\\(4,16]\to3\\(16,65536]\to4\\(65536,2.003529930406\cdots\times10^{19728}]\to5\\\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

I got it: this algorithm has a nearly-constant complexity, specifically the complexity is $\Theta(\log^{*}(n))$ where $\log^{*}(n) \le 5 \ \forall n \le 2^{16}$

Comment: How long does it take to calculate log_2 (n)? Surely not constant time?

Comment: It surely takes $O(\log(n))$ time to calculate that (just check how many bits are present. So if you want to also consider the time that is spent on calculating the logs, the answer will be $O(\log(n)\log^*(n))$

Comment: @nirshahar: $\lg n+\lg\lg n+\lg\lg\lg n+\cdots=O(\log n)$, no ?

Comment: @nirshahar: from Gonnet, the time to compute a logarithm is $M(n)\lg n$, where $M(n)=O(n\log n\log\log n)$ denotes the time for a multiplication. So that leads us to $O(n\log^2n\log\log n)$.